# Django Rest Framework receiving a simple Json Array whose model does not exist

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am receiving this json body

```
{
    "skills" : [
        "First skill",
        "Second skills",
        "Third skills"
        ]
}
```

I do not have a model for it and I am doing something like this. I have read from other posts that in this case I could inherit from `views.APIView` which I am trying to do.

```
class SkillsSubscription(serializers.Serializer):
   skills = serializers.CharField(required=True,)
```

and in the view I am doing something like this

```
class CreateUpdateEmployeeSkillsSubscription_APIView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        results = SkillsSubscription(request.data,many=True).data
        return Response(xxx)
```

I get an exception when I use that serializer. This is the exception.

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `skills` on serializer `SkillsSubscription`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'skills'.
```

Any suggestions on how I could obtain the contents in the skills array ?

Comment: did you try https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield? `ListField`

Answer (score 0):

Based on error, it looks like request.data is string. 
Try json.loads before passing it to serializer.

```
import json
class CreateUpdateEmployeeSkillsSubscription_APIView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
       post_data = json.loads(request.data)
       results = SkillsSubscription(post_data,many=True).data
       return Response(xxx)
```